# What is the difference between a monolithic architecture and a 3-tier architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, microservices, 3-tier

I have an application which is packaged as a single ear file deployed on WebSphere. Inside the package, the code is organized in to UI files, Business Logic files and Database related files. Now, is this a monolithic application or a 3-tier architecture?

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing wrong things.  Monolithic application need to be compared against Micro Services. In monolithic application; you deploy all the features/api end-points in a single EAR/WAR file; i.e. single JVM. In micro-services they are deployed in multiple JVMs. Note that in Monolithic architecture also you have multiple REST end points exposed.

3 tier, or 2 tier or N tier architectures is a different concept. It says how many subsystems/modules your application is divided like database layer, client layer, application logic layer.  Hence, monolithic as well microservices both can be n tier applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Deepak. So, technically a monolith or a micro-service application can be a 3-tier architecture?

Comment: @DeepakSinghal while searching, I found on different platforms that a monolith application is single-tiered by nature and self-contained. So, by your explanation, do you mean that a 3-tier application with a monolith business logic layer is considered a monolith application?

Comment: @AmrSaeed Monolith can be 3-tier also. Before kubernetes came into picture; I used to build monolith applications ; and ofcourse 3 tier.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a EAR and what is in it is a packaging choice.  Your same application can be deployed in multiple ears in multiple Java EE containers on one or more servers.   The EJB-jars and WARs are intended to do that.   With Java EE you choose how to distribute you application across the containers and nodes based on what make sense.

Technically a tiered application is one where the layers can be independently deployed, distributed and accessed.   I.e. my business logic can be on 5 servers in 9 ejb containers and accessed by 3 user interfaces that could be desktop, mobile, web etc.  And possibly parts of different applications.

The more traditional definition of a monolith was an application that wasn't tier. Specifically that its parts cannot be composed in to other applications at runtime